# Python хелп плз

Tags: python-3.x

Написать программу:

> Ввести одномерный массив из n элементов. Вычислить сумму всех
>   отрицательных чисел, их количество и сумму всех положительных чисел.

```
a = [3, -4, -1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 5, -5, -3, -4, 10, -10, 1, -2] 
sum1 = sum2 = 0 
for i in a: if i > 0: 
    sum1 += i 
else: 
    sum2 += i 
print('Сумма положительных:', sum1, 'Сумма отрицательных:', sum2, sep='\n')
```

Не получается вычислить количество отрицательных и положительных числе в массиве и вывести их на экран.

Comment: Какой хелп нужен, что не получается-то?

Comment: Не вижу никаких препятствий для того что-бы Вы написали эту программу. А Вы видите? Если да - напишите какие сложности у Вас возникли при написании этой программы. Вам с удовольствием помогут понять в чем проблема, подскажут что нужно изучить и что можно почитать на эту тему. Если же Вы зашли в тупик и все уже испробовали, а противная ошибка все не фиксится - давайте Код Вашей программы и напишите что за ошибка вылезает. Напишите как Вы ее пытались исправить. Уважайте время других участников сообщества и Вам с удовольствием помогут разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Хорошо было бы добавить волшебное слово "пожалуйста".

Comment: a = [3, -4, -1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 5, -5, -3, -4, 10, -10, 1, -2]
sum1 = sum2 = 0
for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        sum1 += i
    else:
        sum2 += i
print('Сумма положительных:', sum1, 'Сумма отрицательных:', sum2, sep='\n')

Comment: у меня не получается вывести колличество положительных и отрицательных чисел в массиве

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [3, -4, -1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 5, -5, -3, -4, 10, -10, 1, -2]
more_then_ziro = [i for i in a if i > 0]
less_then_ziro = [i for i in a if i < 0]

print(f'Сумма положительных: {sum(more_then_ziro)}\nСумма отрицательных: {sum(less_then_ziro)}')
print(f'Количество положительных: {len(more_then_ziro)}\nКоличество отрицательных: {len(less_then_ziro)}')
# Сумма положительных: 29
# Сумма отрицательных: -31
# Количество положительных: 7
# Количество отрицательных: 8
```

Comment: Вот этому - `more_then_ziro.__len__()` - не надо учить.

Comment: @Эникейщик, кстати, позвольте поинтересоваться, ну мне так, чисто для самообразования (без сарказма). Почему Вы не рекомендуете использовать такой синтаксис?

Comment: Потому что магический метод не зря назван магическим и начинается с двух подчеркиваний. Потому что все ваши коллеги-программисты используют len() и .__len__() будет сбивать с толку. Потому что если такая функция не имплементирована, то len() выдаст TypeError, а не AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, -4, -1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 5, -5, -3, -4, 10, -10, 1, -2]
sum1, sum2 = 0, 0
i1, i2 = 0, 0
for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        sum1 += i
        i1 += 1
    if i < 0:
        sum2 += i
        i2 += 1

print('Сумма положительных:', sum1, 'Сумма отрицательных:', sum2, sep='\n')
print('Число положительных цифр:', i1 )
print('Число отрицательных цифр:', i2 )
```